# Where is the kernel time stored in memory in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

For an assignment I have to use a video driver and system timer handler to display the current running time of the Linux system to the corner of the screen.

However, I have not found anywhere that points me into the direction of obtaining the system time from the kernel when my program runs.  I am guessing it is in kernel memory at some address and I can just do something like:

```
hour = get_word(MEM_LOCATION_OF_HOUR);
sec = get_word(MEM_LOCATION_OF_SEC);
ect...
```

But I cannot find out if this is possible. My guess is that we are not allowed to use library calls like clock() but if that is the only possible way then maybe we are.

Thanks

Comment: Are you writing a kernel module or a user space application?

Comment: both. I am running in umode then switching to kernel to do the timer handling tho, so the memory space is kernel space during the interupts

Comment: The book 'Linux Device Drivers` is available online.  You'll gain a lot of insight by reading chapter 7. http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch07.pdf

Comment: You can read the internal HW clock i.e TimeStampCounter (tsc) and export it via syscall interface, since you're doing both Kernel and usermode stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Can't use library calls? - that's just craziness.  Anyway:

`getnstimeofday(struct timespec *ts);` is one of many methods from ***[here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time/timekeeping.c)***

Comment: yeah well this class is Operating Systems and we basically build an entire kernel from boot loader to finished basic kernel, so we are supposed to implement alot of the low level system stuff ourselves. Ill check that out tho

Answer (score 0):

In kernel, **ktime** can be used.

a simple example(for calculating time diff) for your reference.

```
#include <linux/ktime.h>

int fun()
{
ktime_t entry_stamp, now;
s64 delta;

/* Get the current time .*/
entry_stamp = ktime_get();

/* Do your Stuff... */

now = ktime_get();
delta = ktime_to_ns(ktime_sub(now, entry_stamp));
printk(KERN_INFO "Time Taken:%lld ns to execute\n",(long long)delta);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the Real-time clock holds the correct values on boot. The CMOS contains all the needed info.

Here is a link to what I found. http://wiki.osdev.org/CMOS#The_Real-Time_Clock